# React change component state in a fetch, leads to Object not valid as a React child error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to JavaScript and React since this morning. I'm trying to print the IP of the client directly. To do that, I use `fetch`.
If instead of changing the state, I decided to `.then(() => console.log(data))`, I can see the IP inside the json.`

```
class GetPublicIP extends Component {

     state={
        ip: "Analyzing..."
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then(ipData => {this.setState({ip: ipData})})
        }

    render(){
        return <div><h1>{this.state.ip}</h1></div>;
    }
}

export default GetPublicIP;
```

However, if I try to modify the state, I get this:
`Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with key {ip})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked your code in a sandbox, ipData is returning an object, including { ip: "..." }, so you are setting the state to => `{ ip: { ip: "200.105.212.101" } }`  try:

```
   componentDidMount() {
     fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
     .then((data) => data.json())
     .then(ip => this.setState(ip))
   }
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. But I'm not sure why. How does `this.setState` know which state I want to change, in a case where I have multiple states?

Comment: No problem, I would encourage you to read the React documentation to get a more clear insight: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged but yeah, the merging between states is shallow according to the documentation, so it leaves the other state properties intact.